# pyspark map function not showing output

Tags: pyspark

Here some simple code:

```
%python
allPaths=dbutils.fs.ls("/user/hive/warehouse")
allPathsFiltered = map(lambda x:(x[0]),allPaths)
matching = [s for s in allPathsFiltered if "tabx" in s]

print(list(allPaths))
print(list(allPathsFiltered))
print(list(matching))
```

returns:

```
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/aaa/', name='aaa/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/bbb/', name='bbb/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/example_03/', name='example_03/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/sox/', name='sox/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/sox2/', name='sox2/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/sox3/', name='sox3/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/src/', name='src/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/src2/', name='src2/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/tabx/', name='tabx/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/taby/', name='taby/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/vrba/', name='vrba/', size=0), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/zzz/', name='zzz/', size=0)]
[]
['dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/tabx/']
```

Why does the 2nd print not show any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allPathsFiltered` is an iterator, and you have already iterated through it when defining `matching`, so if you try to iterate through it again using `list(allPathsFiltered)` it won't return anything.

You can try

```
allPaths = dbutils.fs.ls("/user/hive/warehouse")
allPathsFiltered = list(map(lambda x:(x[0]),allPaths))
matching = [s for s in allPathsFiltered if "tabx" in s]
```

Personally I prefer list comprehensions though, like

```
allPathsFiltered = [x[0] for x in allPaths]
```

Comment: Knew it would be something like that, but could not place it.  Cheers